# How to solve this connectivity configuration cast exception?

Tags: java, connection, sap-business-technology-platform

I am trying to run some tests on an endpoint of my application but I got a  class cast exception.

I get the error when I try to reach the endpoint (localhost) from the same machine I am running my code. I don't have the same problem when I make the request to a different machine (although the code on the server may vary from my local source, I am pretty sure this section does not)

I am using this link as reference [ConnectivityConfiguration API](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/4da3b13c88ce4220bbd56a4361799668.html)

And this is my code:

```
private synchronized ConnectivityConfiguration lookupConnectivityConfiguration() throws IOException {
    try {
        if (this.localConnectivityConfiguration == null) { 
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            this.localConnectivityConfiguration = (ConnectivityConfiguration) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/connectivityConfiguration");
        }
        return this.localConnectivityConfiguration;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                        
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I am expecting to get a `com.sap.core.connectivity.api.configurationConnectivityConfiguration` object when the method is called but instead I get the below error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.sap.core.connectivity.apiext.local.LocalConnectivityConfiguration
> cannot be cast to
> com.sap.core.connectivity.api.configuration.ConnectivityConfiguration

and I am not sure where this class comes or should be imported from `com.sap.core.connectivity.apiext.local.LocalConnectivityConfiguration`.